# How would i do a VLOOKUP to find a exact match to a number in a string of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following sheet with a column with a list of numbers and a column with a name

```
124, 3, 7, 1, 41      Sarah
9, 76, 161, 8         Chris
91, 41, 21, 4, 2      Alan
```

I would like to be able to VLOOKUP the columns to match a single whole number to a name like this

Output:

```
1     Sarah
2     Alan
3     N\A
4     Alan
...
```

here is what I have: `=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!A$1:C$3,2,FALSE)`

The problem I am having is that it is finding partial numbers in the string e.g.

1 is in "124" so it is a match but not the full number

how would I solve this?

Comment: What does `3`--> `N/A`? when `3` exists in the same row as `Sarah`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INDEX/MATCH` in an array formula, specifying that the desired number must be preceded by "`,`" and followed by the same string:

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$3,MATCH("*, "&D1&", *",", "&A$1:A$3&", ",0))
```

note: you will need <kbd>CRTL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm this formula

[image]

Comment: Does this work for numbers at the start or end of the list?

Comment: Yes it does: notice that in the `Match`, we add "`, `" not only to the term being matched, but also to the values in the range being searched. (That's why it needs to be an array formula). I modified the sample data to reflect this ("Alan" matches "4" even though `"4" is the last value listed

Comment: 124 is not preceded by a ", " could I maybe use regex to say  ![0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function pukoolv(v As Variant, r As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, temp As String, temp2 As String

    arr = r
    pukoolv = ""
    temp2 = CStr(v)

     For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        temp = Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", "")
        brr = Split(temp, ",")
        For Each b In brr
            If b = temp2 Then
                pukoolv = arr(i, UBound(arr, 2))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next b
    Next i
End Function
```

Use it like:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=pukoolv(lookup_value,lookup_table)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

You can have your lookup do something a little more sophisticated. For instance:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!A$1:C$3,2,FALSE)
```

would become:

```
=VLOOKUP("* "&A1&", *",Sheet1!A$1:C$3,2,FALSE)
```

Note the space added to the asterisk preceding `A1` and the comma and space added after `A1` in forming the lookup value.

A full number, like "124" will be preceded by a space and followed by a comma and a space while a portion of it, like "24" will NOT be able to say that.

With the more on-point lookup value, your difficulty goes away entirely.